# stackoverflowerror when processing depth-first-iteration via scala

Tags: java, scala, recursion, stack-overflow

I intend to recursively iterate all grids within a circle zone, the code below will perform depth-first-search. But after 204 stacks, `java.lang.StackOverflowError` will be thrown.

```
def geohash_circle_around_point(lat: Double, lon: Double, radius: Double) = {

  def expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter: GeoHash, ghCur: GeoHash, buffer: collection.mutable.Set[GeoHash]): Unit = {
    // MARK: DP: check whether it's iterated already or not
    if(buffer contains ghCur)  {
      return
    }
    buffer += ghCur

    for(ghAround <- get4GeoHashAround(ghCur))  {
      if(distanceBetweenGeohash(ghCenter, ghAround) <= radius)  {
        expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter, ghAround, buffer)
      }
    }
  }

  def get4GeoHashAround(gh: GeoHash): Array[GeoHash] = {
    Array(gh.getNorthernNeighbour, gh.getSouthernNeighbour, gh.getWesternNeighbour, gh.getEasternNeighbour)
  }

  def distanceBetweenGeohash(gh1: GeoHash, gh2: GeoHash) = {
    haversine(gh1.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLatitude, gh1.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLongitude, gh2.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLatitude, gh2.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLongitude)
  }

  val ghCenter = GeoHash.withBitPrecision(lat, lon, 40)
  val s = collection.mutable.Set[GeoHash]()
  expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter, ghCenter, s)
  s.map(_.getBoundingBox)
}
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.index(HashSet.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.findElemImpl(FlatHashTable.scala:126)
  at scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.containsElem(FlatHashTable.scala:121)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.containsElem(HashSet.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.contains(HashSet.scala:57)
  at Test$.Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1(Test.scala:32)
  at Test$$anonfun$Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1$1.apply(Test.scala:39)
  at Test$$anonfun$Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1$1.apply(Test.scala:37)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at Test$.Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1(Test.scala:37)
  at Test$$anonfun$Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1$1.apply(Test.scala:39)
  at Test$$anonfun$Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1$1.apply(Test.scala:37)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at Test$.Test$$expand_neighbors_impl$1(Test.scala:37)
....
```

Could anyone give some suggestions? Thanks!

**P.S.**

Implementation for `equals` and `hashCode` for `GeoHash`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == this) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(obj instanceof GeoHash) {
            GeoHash other = (GeoHash)obj;
            if(other.significantBits == this.significantBits && other.bits == this.bits) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public int hashCode() {
    byte f = 17;
    int f1 = 31 * f + (int)(this.bits ^ this.bits >>> 32);
    f1 = 31 * f1 + this.significantBits;
    return f1;
}
```

Comment: I believe `contains` always returns false as there is no `equals` method for `Geohash`? If that's the case then it'll keep adding the same object.

Comment: @DarshanMehta, for `HashSet`, the method `hashCode` is also needed.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet it goes without saying..

Comment: Java initially gives a small stack for recursion and other stuff so when you call more than 100,000 recursion functions(DFS calls) you may get StackOverFlow Exception. You can solve it in two ways. 1) You can implement your own stack which will work as recursion stack. 2) You can create a thread and allocate the memory according to your maximum requirement.

Comment: GeoHash has equals implemented @DarshanMehta

Comment: Both `hashcode` and `equals` is implemented, and the stack is only 200+ depth @CyrilleCorpet

Comment: also, since you're using `Double`s, strict equality can be difficult to achieve... Is it possible to show the implementation for `equals` and `hashcode`?

Comment: It's appended @CyrilleCorpet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you really need more than 200 calls at `40` precision...

You might want to consider rewriting your recursion to be tail-recursive, in order to be optimized by the compiler. Here's a way to do this:

```
@tailrec
def expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter: GeoHash, toGoThrough: List[GeoHash], buffer: Set[GeoHash] = Set()): Set[GeoHash] = {
  toGoThrough.headOption match {
    case None => buffer
    case Some(ghCur) =>
      if (buffer contains ghCur) {
        expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter, toGoThrough.tail, buffer)
      }
      else {
        val neighbors = get4GeoHashAround(ghCur).filter(distanceBetweenGeohash(ghCenter, _) <= radius)
        expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter, neighbors ++: toGoThrough, buffer + ghCur)
      }
  }
}

def expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter: GeoHash, ghCur: GeoHash): Set[GeoHash] =
  expand_neighbors_impl(ghCenter, List(ghCur))
```

Besides using tail-recursion, it avoids using a mutable `Set`, which might give some unexpected complication.